# Function to remove set of character in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following function to remove set of character from a given string:

```
ALTER function removalspchar(@Name varchar(30))
returns varchar(500)
As 
Begin 
declare @sub char(1)

while patindex('%[-:;&, ]%',@Name)>0
begin 
 set @sub=substring(@Name,patindex('%[-:;&, ]%',@Name),1)
 set @Name = replace(@Name,@sub,'')
end

return @Name
End

select dbo.removalspchar('CORP - Sovereign & Public Finance')
```

But the ouput of the following function coming as : CORPSovereignPublicFina rather than CORPSovereignPublicFinance.

Can somebody let me know what I am doing incorrect or a better way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you should increase length of param `(@Name varchar(30))` say `(@Name varchar(100))`.